# Sorting a set of results with pre-ordered items

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of pre-ordered items (order by score ASC) like:

```json
[{
 "id": "id2",
 "score": 1
}, {
 "id": "id12",
 "score": 1
}, {
 "id": "id8",
 "score": 1.4
}, {
 "id": "id9",
 "score": 1.4
}, {
 "id": "id14",
 "score": 1.75
}, { 
...
}]
```

Let's say I have an elasticsearch index with a massive of items. Note that there's no "score" field in indexed documents.

Now I want elasticsearch to return only those items with ids in the said list. Ok, this one is easy. I'm now stuck at sorting the result. That means I need the result to be sorted exactly as my pre-ordered list above.

Any suggestion for me to achieve that?

I'm not an English native speaker, so sorry for my grammar and words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As version of 7.4, Elastic introduced pinned query that promotes selected documents to rank higher than those matching a given query. In your case this search query should return what you want:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "pinned" : {
            "ids" : ["id2", "id12", "id8"],
            "organic" : {
                other queries
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information you can check Elasticsearch official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/query-dsl-pinned-query.html).